# Slow access to multidimensional array's items

Tags: ios, arrays, multidimensional-array, swift

I am experiencing one minor problem with Swift.

I am porting my old C++ code to it, and there are several places where I am using two-dimensional arrays.

Swift code now looks like:

```
var m_blocksSave:Array<Array<Int>>

var columns = 32
var rows = 32

//fill array with 0
    for column in 0..<columns {
        var columnArray = Array<Int>()
        for row in 0..<rows {
            columnArray.append(0)//default is 0
        }
        m_blocksSave.append(columnArray)

    }
```

Then I want to check this array, find 1 for example. In fact any access to array's item creates a HUGE slowdown.

This code for example can take up to 4 seconds on my machine (regardless of environment, I can use iOS with simulator or run it as native OS X app):

```
    for var i=0;i<columns;i++
    {
        for var j=0;j<rows;j++
        {
            let intVariable = m_blocksSave[i][j]//this thing is slow
        }
    }
```

What can I do in this situation and what is going on? Why is it so slow?

Comment: Which compiler option did you set for optimization?

Comment: its really taking time!

Comment: I have tried all options from -ONone to -OFast.

Comment: Tried today to make this test again and everything went ok! So this is just a limitation of beta software, GM seed is OK now.

Answer (score 0):

you can refer to :  [Most efficient way to access multi-dimensional arrays in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27139437/most-efficient-way-to-access-multi-dimensional-arrays-in-swift). 
In one word, 2D array is not so good right now, you need to construct your own 2D Array with 1D array.